# Bootstrap columns overlapping in fluid layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure out what is happening with this for quite some time with no luck. I have stripped my code down o the most basic example of what I'm trying a achieve and cannot figure out why my columns are overlapping and not stacking.

The failing jfiddle can be found here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rB9Md/

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="border:1px solid black; min-width:400px; width:400px">
                span4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="border:1px solid red; min-width:400px; width: 400px">
                span4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="border:1px solid green; min-width:400px; width: 400px">
                span4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why are the columns not stacking as expected??
I have tried many variations of widths, max-width, min-width in various places with no success. 
I would assume that once the span4 column shrinks to be smaller than the contents set width it would stack....

Comment: the `min-width` and `width` are messing with it... remove the inline styles.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZRpSZ/1/

You don't want to use `min-width`, `width` styles in this case, if you can avoid it.

Bootstrap's `span4` is already going to make that column span 33% (4/12) of the screen width, or collapse if the screen width is too small.  When using bootstrap, you want to use the grid system to layout your columns as much as you can.  For reference, see [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

If you need the columns to be 400px wide always, you won't be able to get them side by side in most screen widths.  So you should consider how responsive you wish to be.

> The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns, making for a
>   940px wide container without responsive features enabled. With the
>   responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide
>   depending on your viewport. Below 767px viewports, the columns become
>   fluid and stack vertically.

When the columns stack, you can set `max-width:400px` so they stay only that wide.

Comment: This does not seem practical to me. Without the width the columns shrink to around 200px before they stack. At what point does it decide to stack. 200px make the 3 columns look terrible. Then once they stack they are fine.

Comment: Fluid rows are for fluid content.  If your columns aren't fluid, you shouldn't use it.  That being said, bootstrap grid is smaller than 1200px, so having 3 side by side 400px columns isn't going to happen until you change the dimensions in your bootstrap, or you don't use bootstrap.

Comment: Here is a bootstrap-less version using media queries that may suit your needs better:  http://jsfiddle.net/nS6az/2/

Comment: 400px is just an example size. I have 3 columns in the page and they do not stack until they are incredibly small. They resize quite well  but they get so thin that they would look 100 times better being stack on top of each other at a given browser width. This being the intention of the design. 3 columns which will stack for presentations.  I still fail to understand the trigger for a stack. It seem they just decided to stack at some magic point which is no good for my purpose. If i knew maybe I could manipulate the trigger.

Comment: The magical triggers are called **media queries**.  All bootstrap does is define them with predefined classes and widths to make web layouts easier.  I'm using a simple one in the last fiddle mentioned.  `@media (min-width:1230px)` only executes css rules when the width is at least that large. I picked that number since that's the minimum size the 400px columns can sit side by side (with padding).  You just need to figure out what works for your site.